# When I front WSO2 public nexus repo with an Azure CDN endpoint, it gives 502-Bad gateway error

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I set up an “Azure CDN premium from Verizon” profile and created an endpoint with the configurations shown below.

Name: my-public-nexus-11111
Other configurations:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfYDA.png)

I wanted to download an artifact from the wso2 public nexus repository (artifact link: https://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/wso2/carbon/org.wso2.carbon.core/4.4.10/org.wso2.carbon.core-4.4.10.jar ).
But when I used my CDN endpoint to download this artifact, it gives me a “502 Bad gateway” error.
(Link with the CDN endpoint: https://my-public-nexus-11111.azureedge.net/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/wso2/carbon/org.wso2.carbon.core/4.4.10/org.wso2.carbon.core-4.4.10.jar )

What is the reason for this behavior?

Also just to check whether I‘ve misconfigured something when creating the endpoint, I created another endpoint with the below configurations:

Name: my-test-mvn-central-without-path
oher configurations:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFUkX.png)

Then I tried to download this artifact with the CDN endpoint link: ​​https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/siddhi/siddhi-core/5.0.1/siddhi-core-5.0.1.jar

This can be achieved. The link with the CDN endpoint:
https://my-test-mvn-central-without-path.azureedge.net/maven2/io/siddhi/siddhi-core/5.0.1/siddhi-core-5.0.1.jar

Therefore why the previous CDN endpoint gave me 502 bad gateway error (When configured wso2 public nexus repo as the origin) ?

Also, is it possible to send a request header to the backend?

(Please note that CDN links might not work because I need to stop CDN endpoints to avoid unnecessary costs)

<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment like below***

I created an Azure CDN endpoint with premium verzion like below:

[image]

> *When I used my CDN endpoint to download  artifact, it gives me a “502 Bad gateway” error what is the reason for this behavior?*

This error may occur when an HTTP protocol failure occurs between a server and an HTTP proxy. It can't be parsed when customer origin server returns an invalid response to an edge server.

- Use ***Flush DNS cache***, In your system DNS cache keeps specific information about the websites you visit.

Try to use **`ipconfig /flushdns`**

[image]

Try to disable Temporarily disable  [CDN](https://www.keycdn.com/support/502-bad-gateway) or firewall.

- ***In WordPress -> Under setting,  click CDN -> Disable CDN -> Save.***
- ***Or you can temporarily disable the firewall setting to fix the issue like below:***

*In control Panel -> System and Security -> security and maintenance -> Turn Windows Firewall on or off -> Turn off Windows Firewall*

[image]

[image]

[image]

As per *Anton Kucer*  check whether Service Name Indication is turned on at your origin and try to disable [SNI setup](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SECURITY/en-US/b745d9a3-54e4-4b5f-be61-1028e3d9f678/azure-cdn-endpoint-giving-502-bad-gateway-with-https?forum=azurecdn) for SSL binding to resolve this issue. Verify the network connectivity and check whether necessary ports and protocols are open and configured properly.